# What is the meaning of "I'm happy for you to do something"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

If somebody told me:

> I'm happy for you to make this change.

Does it means that he is going to do it, or does it means he gave me his permission to make the change, but I am the one who will act?

Comment: I wouldn't say "benediction", that's a formal blessing given by a priest.  You might be getting mixed up with the phrase "You have my blessing(s)", which is a *figure of speech* meaning "you have my permission", which is what the phrase in your question means, too.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - Anyone can give a benediction. It is not limited to priests or services. "May the road rise up to meet you. May the wind always be at your back..." is a common one in Ireland.

Comment: It does mean you are now on the hook.

Comment: @medica Ok, I stand corrected, but it's still wrong in the context of the question, ie it's not a synonym for permission.

Comment: @Max: It seems to me [*Are you happy for me to (make this change)?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22are+you+happy+for+me+to%22) is ***always*** a request for "permission".

Comment: @MaxWilliams I've edited the question to avoid confusion with the religious theme, thank you for noticing it.

Comment: I would normally do this or I am too lazy, so you have my permission and I expect you to do it unless you tell me otherwise

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree.

Answer (score 4):

I would take that as an indication that the other person would have no objection to your making the change yourself. If the other person was going to carry out the action he would say "I'd be happy to make that change"